# Delphi: How to use TJvRichEdit to load or save text and images (not just .bmp) to file or firebird blob field?

Tags: delphi, stream, rtf, richedit, jvcl

Regarding TJvRichEdit and Delphi... How?

1. Load/Save rtf (including text and images - not only .bmp) to/from a file?
2. Read/Write rtf (including text and images - not only .bmp) to/from Firebird blob field?
3. Automatically convert screendump pasted from clipboard (Ctrl-V) into .jpg format before it is inserted into the TJvRichEdit rtf?

Guidance/advice, examples/code and useful URLs are all helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The JEDI Online Help at http://help.delphi-jedi.org is *not* useful. Reading the source code in JvRichEdit.pas was helpful but I was still left with a lot of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding 3 i would advice to create bitmap load from clipboard (see LoadFromClipboardFormat, SaveToClipboardFormat), convert to jpeg save to clipboard, richedit paste from clipboard,

Converting from bitmap to jpeg:

```
Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
jpg.Assign(Bitmap);
jpg.CompressionQuality := 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the blob field goes, use a [tBlobStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBTables.TBlobStream) and the components SaveToStream / LoadFromStream methods.  For a file, use a [tFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TFileStream) with the same methods.

Answer (score 0):

Found a demo (..\jvcl\examples\JvRichEdit\EditorDemo.dpr) that comes with the JVCL download. It compiles and runs and looks like it may contain the code that answers part 1 of the question.